# Get List Of Connected Users From Ratchet WebSocket

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet

I am trying my hands on websockets and i think its working too. I created a dummy php file to start a websocket server then at onOpen i am attaching to user ID of each clients so i can access it later or  can use their ID to send message to them. After starting and connecting to the websocket, i try to access list of users connected to the websocket like this

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once('websocket.php');

// Test Connected Device/Users
$connectedClients = $webSocketServer->getClients();
foreach ($connectedClients as $userId => $client) {
    echo "User ID: $userId, Connection: $client\n";
}



?>
```

This file shows error that port is already in use, its right because websocket server is running on 20081 port and all users connected to websocket on this port too.

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught RuntimeException: Failed to listen on &quot;tcp: //0.0.0.0:20081&quot;: Address already in use (EADDRINUSE) in /home/bitnami/vendor/react/socket/src/TcpServer.php:184
Stack trace:
#0 /home/bitnami/vendor/react/socket/src/Server.php(77): React\Socket\TcpServer-&gt;__construct()
#1 /home/bitnami/vendor/cboden/ratchet/src/Ratchet/Server/IoServer.php(59): React\Socket\Server-&gt;__construct()
#2 /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/net/websocket.php(171): Ratchet\Server\IoServer: :factory()
#3 /opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs/net/test.php(6): require_once('/opt/bitnami/ap...')
#4 {main
}
  thrown in <b>/home/bitnami/vendor/react/socket/src/TcpServer.php</b> on line <b>184</b><br />
```

Websocket

```
<?php

require_once("/home/bitnami/vendor/autoload.php");
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;

class WebSocketHandler implements MessageComponentInterface {
    private $clients;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage();
    }
    

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // Handle new WebSocket connection
        
        $request = $conn->httpRequest;
        // Get the action
        $action = $request->getHeaderLine("action");
        // Check if the action is "addClient"
        if ($action === "addClient") {
            // Add the user to the list of connected users
            $userId = $request->getHeaderLine('userId');            
            // Save the user ID in the resourceId property of the connection
            $conn->resourceId = $userId;
            // Add the connection to the clients list
            $this->clients->attach($conn, $userId);
        }
        file_put_contents('zee1.log',print_r($userId.' '.$action,true));        
    }

    

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // The connection is closed, remove it, as we can no longer send it messages
        $this->clients->detach($conn);

    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
        $conn->close();
    }
    
    private function findClientConnection($userId) {
        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
            if ($client->resourceId === $userId) {
                return $client;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public function getClients(){
        $connectedClients = [];
        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
            $connectedClients[$client->resourceId] = $client;
        }
        return $connectedClients;
    }   
    
}
    
$webSocketServer = new WebSocketHandler();

    $server = IoServer::factory(
            new HttpServer(
                new WsServer(
                    $webSocketServer
                )
            ),
            20081
        );


    $server->run();
```

I stuck to get connected users from websocket, but not able to find any docs or help which can help me to get active/connected users (with their IDs).